# how to streaming raspberry pi to android

Tags: android, opencv, streaming, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to do an image process with Raspberry Pi 4 that has Raspbian in my project. My project consists of 2 parts. The first part is the image process and 2nd part is streaming the image that processed to android devices.

I'm using python with OpenCV and the first part is done so I'm trying to do the second part but I couldn't. I install the apache server and tried streaming the movie but I could get an image that not processed on the local web address. I tried too many methods but couldn't get any results.
How could I stream the image that processed to the android device?